# How to select items in tab menu of Vimperator

Tags: firefox, fedora, vimperator

After clicking `t` Vimperator shows up a tab window with Smart Completitions, and for example when typing `addon` it shows the URLs with the keyword on it.

What I want is to select the URL I want from the list.

I think it might be possible in a manner similar to following links or somehow activated by `;` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the highlighted row forwards and backwards through the list respectively. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to load the highlighted completion.

Comment: I tried that it didn't work, it just locks to the first item

Comment: Sounds like something else in your browser is grabbing the key press. This works for me in vanilla Firefox + Vimperator. What's it like when you disable other plugins?